# Is List.Contains fully comparison-wise equivalent to List.IndexOf?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

MSDN description of [List.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says

> This method determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the IEquatable.Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).

and the description of [List.IndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says

> This method determines equality using the default equality comparer EqualityComparer.Default for T, the type of values in the list.

and [EqualityComparer.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) description says

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

Which is kinda suspicious - the description of `Contains` only mentions `IEquatable` and it's possible to put stuff that does not implement `IEquatable` into a `List`.

So I'd guess they simply use the same semantics and perhaps `Contains()` reuses `IndexOf()`.

So are they fully equivalent comparison-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

- No, `Contains()` does not reuse `IndexOf()`
- Yes, they are equivalent comparison-wise

I decompiled (ReSharper) and saw that eventually both use abstract `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(T x, T y)` method. The `Default` instance for `EqualityComparer<T>` is initialized (and cached) according to type T.

**List.Contains**

```
EqualityComparer<T> @default = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
// for loop
if (@default.Equals(this._items[index], item))
    return true;
```

**List.IndexOf**

```
return Array.IndexOf<T>(this._items, item, 0, this._size);
```

**Array.IndexOf**

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    // Some assertions
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.IndexOf(array, value, startIndex, count);
}
```

**EqualityComparer.IndexOf**

```
internal virtual int IndexOf(T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    // for loop
    if (this.Equals(array[index], value))
        return index;
}
```

And this is how **EqualityComparer.Default** is instantiated

```
public static EqualityComparer<T> Default
{
  get
  {
    EqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer = EqualityComparer<T>.defaultComparer;
    if (equalityComparer == null)
    {
      equalityComparer = EqualityComparer<T>.CreateComparer();
      EqualityComparer<T>.defaultComparer = equalityComparer;
    }
    return equalityComparer;
  }
}

private static EqualityComparer<T> CreateComparer()
{
  RuntimeType genericParameter1 = (RuntimeType) typeof (T);

  if ((Type) genericParameter1 == typeof (byte))
    return (EqualityComparer<T>) new ByteEqualityComparer();
  // Some ifs go on
  else
    return (EqualityComparer<T>) new ObjectEqualityComparer<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> So I'd guess they simply use the same semantics and perhaps Contains()
>   reuses IndexOf().

No it doesn't.

List.Contains is implemented as:

From [Reference Source .NET Framework 4.5.1 - Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#521b9f7129105e15)

```
public bool Contains(T item) {
    if ((Object) item == null) {
        for(int i=0; i<_size; i++)
            if ((Object) _items[i] == null)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        EqualityComparer<T> c = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        for(int i=0; i<_size; i++) {
            if (c.Equals(_items[i], item)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Where as `List<T>.IndexOf` uses `Array.IndexOf`

[Source:](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#242756beb6e8749e) `List<T>.IndexOf`

```
public int IndexOf(T item)
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= -1);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() < Count);
    return Array.IndexOf(_items, item, 0, _size);
}
```

[`Array.IndexOf` is implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs#35ebfdcba4f0e942) as

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }

    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > array.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Index"));
    }

    if (count < 0 || count > array.Length - startIndex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Count"));
    }
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() < array.Length);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.IndexOf(array, value, startIndex, count);

}
```